# AB and BA have identical nonsingular Jordan blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If A and B are square matrices of the same size I know how to show that AB and BA have the same eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials. But I want to show that they have identical nonsingular Jordan Blocks.

I am not really sure how to proceed. Maybe some argument about the dimension of the kernel of AB and BA?

Answer (score 3):

First, let's prove it for invertible $AB$: If $AB$ is invertible, then so is $A$ and $B$. Let \begin{equation}AB=P^{-1}JP.\end{equation} Multiply with $B$ on the left, and $B^{-1}$ on the right: \begin{equation}BA=BP^{-1}JPB^{-1}.\end{equation} So $AB$ and $BA$ have the same Jordan normal form. In fact this works also if only one of $A$ or $B$ is invertible.

So that only leaves the case where both $A$ and $B$ are singular...

---

OK, let's suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are singular - after consulting *Matrix Theory* by Zhang, I can provide the following:
Consider this identity:
$$\begin{bmatrix} I & -A \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{bmatrix},$$ which shows that $$\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{bmatrix}$$ are similar.

Now I make use of the following theorem: Let $M$ be a $n \times n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_r$. Let $J$ be a Jordan canonical matrix similar to $M$. The number of simple Jordan blocks $J_m(\lambda_i)$ in $J$, with $m \geq k$, is
$$\text{rank}(M - \lambda_iI)^{k-1} - \text{rank}(M - \lambda_iI)^{k},\quad k=1,2,\ldots$$ (Theorem 5.14 in Cullen's *Matrices and Linear Transformations*).

First the characteristic polynomials of $AB$ and $\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}$ are the same (follows from determinant of a block triangular matrix is the same as the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks). Likewise $BA$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{bmatrix}$ have the same characteristic polynomials. So all the matrices involved have the same eigenvalues.

Now assume $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Notice that for any non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $$\text{rank}\left (\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix} - \lambda I\right ) = \text{rank}(AB - \lambda I) + n.$$ Also $$\text{rank}\left (\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix} - \lambda  I\right )^k = \text{rank}\left (\begin{bmatrix} (AB-\lambda I)^k & 0 \\ D & (-1)^k \lambda^k I\end{bmatrix} \right ) = \text{rank}(AB - \lambda I)^k + n,$$ where the matrix $D$ is some matrix resulting from the multiplication.

Combining this with the theorem mentioned, it follows that $AB$ and $\begin{bmatrix} AB & 0 \\ B & 0\end{bmatrix}$ have the same nonsingular Jordan blocks.

A similar argument will show that $BA$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ B & BA\end{bmatrix}$ have the same nonsingular Jordan blocks. Combining this with the similarity between the block matrices yields the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

*Not totally sure about this approach yet... work in progress*

---

Suppose that $\lambda \neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$.  Let $v$ be an associated eigenvector (noting that $Bv \neq 0$). Then, we have
$$
(BA - \lambda I)(Bv) = 
BAB v - \lambda(Bv) = \\
B[AB - \lambda I]v = 0
$$
In other words, we have
$$
(AB - \lambda I)v = 0 \implies (BA - \lambda I)(Bv) = 0
$$
Similarly, we can note that if $(AB - \lambda I)^n v = 0$, then $(BA - \lambda I)^n (Bv) = 0$.  Thus, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same generalized eigenvectors.  The conclusion would follow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer here avoids getting in the weeds of Jordan Forms and instead involves a small refinement  of the notion of $T-$invariant subspaces.

The basic insight is $B(AB)^n = (BA)^n B$ and  $A(BA)^n = (AB)^n A$ and
write $\mathbb F^n = V = \text{image }(AB)^n \oplus \text{ker }(AB)^n= \text{image }(BA)^n \oplus \text{ker } (BA)^n$

The standard commutativity argument tells us e.g. $(AB)$ commutes with $(AB)^n$ so for $\mathbf z \in \text{image }(AB)^n$ we have $\big((AB)\mathbf z\big) = (AB)(AB)^n \mathbf z' = (AB)^n (AB)\mathbf z'\implies \big((AB)\mathbf z\big) \in  \text{image }(AB)^n$, i.e. $\text{image }(AB)^n$ is $(AB)$ invariant;  $\text{ker }(AB)^n$ is also $(AB)$ invariant [check $(AB)^n (AB)\mathbf z =(AB)(AB)^n\mathbf z=\mathbf 0$ for $\mathbf z\in\text{ker }(AB)^n$].  Notice this implies $(AB)_{\vert \text{ker }(AB)^n}$ is nilpotent and $(AB)_{\vert \text{image }(AB)^n}$ is invertible-- and the latter is what we want to focus on.

$W_1:= \text{image }(AB)^n$ and $W_2:= \text{image }(BA)^n$ with respective bases $\mathbf B_1$ and $\mathbf B_2$
note that $r =\dim W_1 = \dim W_2$, which can be justified e.g. by the following rank inequalities:
$\text{rank}\big((AB)^{n}\big)=\text{rank}\big((AB)^{n+1}\big)=\text{rank}\big(A(BA)^{n}B\big) \leq \text{rank}\big((BA)^{n}\big)$  and by nearly identical argument
$\text{rank}\big((BA)^{n}\big)\leq \text{rank}\big((AB)^{n}\big)\implies \dim W_1 = \dim W_2$

Now for the refinement:
for $\mathbf x \in W_2$ we have $A\mathbf x = A(BA)^n\mathbf x' = (AB)^n (A\mathbf x')\implies \big(A\mathbf x\big)\in W_1$  and by nearly identical argument, $\mathbf y \in W_1\implies \big(B\mathbf y\big)\in W_2$
so $A\mathbf B_2 = \mathbf B_1 M_A $ and $B\mathbf B_1 =\mathbf B_2 M_B$

$\implies (AB)\mathbf B_1 = A\mathbf B_2M_B =\mathbf B_1 M_A M_B$
$\implies M_A, M_B \in GL_r(\mathbb F)$, for avoidance of doubt: this occurs  since  $\ker AB\subseteq \text{ker }(AB)^n$ and $\text{ker }(AB)^n \cap W_1 = \big\{\mathbf 0\big\}$ and  thus $M_B$ is injective hence invertible since square, which implies $M_A$ is as well.  Similarly  $(BA)\mathbf B_2 = B\mathbf B_1 M_A =\mathbf B_2 M_B M_A$.

Thus after choice of bases $\mathbf B_1$ and $\mathbf B_2$ we see $(AB)_{\vert W_1}$ has matrix representation $M_A M_B$, while $(BA)_{\vert W_2}$ has matrix representation $M_B M_A$ and $M_A^{-1}\big(M_A M_B\big)M_A = M_B M_A$ so these two matrices have the same Jordan structure i.e. $(AB)_{\vert W_1}$ and $(BA)_{\vert W_2}$ have the same Jordan structure.